# Wind noise on recorded video

Tags: audio-recording

I have a Panasonic HC-X920 video camera which overall I really like, however it seems very prone to wind noise on the audio when played back. The camera has a connection point for an external mike and I have recently purchased an adapter to take an external mike.  I now don't know which type of mike would be best, I would like a shotgun mike which attaches to the camera, has anyone any experience of this situation and can perhaps recommend an external mike for this purpose.

Comment: What is your budget? What type of material are you shooting? What are you then doing with that material?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. just ordinary family video quite a lot of which happens to be outside so is affected by wind noise on the built in mike. I have seen external mikes with a wind. sock just not sure of which to go for. I edit my video on a laptop then output to my TV. I don't want to spend silly money but would invest a reasonable amount to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Id recommend going with a Rode Mic.

The Rode Shoe Mount Video Mic (around $250-$300) is more compact than even a short short shotgun. Secondly, there is a selector switch on the back that allows the user to select various pickup patterns, from cardiod, to stereo, directional, etc.

Theres a few models, but check BH and Amazon.

An entry level Shotgun would be a Sennheiser, but 1.) Its far less compact, and 2.) Price point for the capsule and power supply will run $500 and up. Lastly, youre going to be limited to XLR out without an adapter.

The Rode Mics to be honest, sound fantastic for their price point.

You can add an accessory Rycote Furry Windjammer to cut down the wind even further beyond the included Foam Windscreen. A Furry Windjammer will give you the best results (pricey but worth it), and last, you can add a lo-cut filter either on the Rode or in post to further reduce wind rumble.